# ! Package animate Error: Missing frame number in \animategraphics command

Tags: beamer, animations, animate

I have a document with 8 frames and I want to include it in my `beamer` as an animated figure, but I'm getting an error of `(! Package animate Error: Missing frame number in \animategraphics command.)` when I'm using this command

```
\animategraphics[width=0.5\textwidth , autoplay,loop]{1}{xxx.pdf}{}{}
```

When I use this command `\includegraphics[scale=0.75]{CEOC400036.pdf}`, it outputs only one frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the file extension `.pdf`, as in this example with multipage PDF file `example-image-a4-numbered.pdf` from `mwe` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{animate,graphicx}


\begin{document}

  \animategraphics[width=0.5\textwidth,autoplay,loop]{1}{example-image-a4-numbered}{}{}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work with me

Comment: Does my example code work for you? Next, does file xxx.pdf exist?